# remove item from array when another item is added to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of numbers and when an item is added to this array the numbers should be replaced by this item.

The problem I'm having is that most of the time it will replace the number, however sometimes it will add the item next to the number.

I also have the same problem when removing the item in that the number will sometimes appear next to the item.

Also It currently allows an item to be added multiple times so that if an item is added twice it will show one instance of the item and the remove button has to be clicked twice to actually remove the item.

How can I prevent the behavior of the number appearing next to the item when being added/removed and also prevent being able to add an item more than once?

https://codesandbox.io/s/jp26jrkk89

**Hello.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import update from 'immutability-helper'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Product from './Product'

const NumberWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex-direction: row;
`

const Numbers = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #808080;
  font-size: 32px;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  min-height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
`

const CardWrap = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 20px;
`

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      placeholder: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      addedArray: [],
      data: [
        { id: 1, header: 'Item 1' },
        { id: 2, header: 'Item 2' },
        { id: 3, header: 'Item 3' },
        { id: 4, header: 'Item 4' }
      ],
      addedItems: [],
    }
  }

  handleAdd = (id) => {
    const nextAdded = [id, ...this.state.addedArray];
    this.setState({
      addedArray: nextAdded,
      addedItems: update(this.state.addedItems, {
        $push: [
          id,
        ],
      })
    })
  }

  handleRemove = (id) => {
    const index = this.state.addedItems.indexOf(id);
    const nextAdded = this.state.addedArray.filter(n => n != id);
    this.setState({
      addedArray: nextAdded,
      addedItems: update(this.state.addedItems, {
        $splice: [
          [index, 1]
        ],
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NumberWrap>
          {
            this.state.placeholder.map(num =>
              <Numbers>
                {this.state.addedArray.filter(n => n == num).length == 0 && num}
                {
                  this.state.data.filter(item => {
                    return this.state.addedItems.indexOf(item.id) === num - 1;
                  }).slice(0, 5).map(item =>
                    <Product {...item} remove={() => { this.handleRemove(item.id) }} />
                    )
                }
              </Numbers>
            )
          }
        </NumberWrap>


        <CardWrap>
          {
            this.state.data.map(item =>
              <Product
                {...item}
                add={() => {
                  this.handleAdd(item.id)
                }}
              />
            )}
        </CardWrap>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Product.js**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Card = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
`;

const Header = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
`;

const AddBtn = styled.button`
  width:100%;
  height: 45px;
`;

const Product = props => {
  const { add, id, header, remove } = props;
  return (
    <Card>
      <Header key={id}>
        {header}
      </Header>
      <AddBtn onClick={add}>Add</AddBtn>
      <AddBtn onClick={remove}>Remove</AddBtn>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: What is the use of addedItems and addedArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the demo :

Please check :

https://codesandbox.io/s/8kl2pkw5m0

---

I have removed the `addedItems` and just used `addedArray`

Here is the one way to stop adding multiple

```
const nextAdded = [...new Set([id, ...this.state.addedArray])];
```

Create a set out of array then gain create it array this way all the duplicate entry will be removed.

Comment: I have one problem with this, if you click on box 4 for instance it will add into the 4th position whereas I need it to go into the first position

Answer (score 2):

In this case it seems easier to work with your items directly and store them in an object.

Check out [my fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zknrojpxo) for a working example.

- Changed `addedItems` to an object
- Changed add handler to use the item object directly

---

```
export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      placeholder: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      data: [
        { id: 1, header: 'Item 1' },
        { id: 2, header: 'Item 2' },
        { id: 3, header: 'Item 3' },
        { id: 4, header: 'Item 4' }
      ],
      addedItems: {},
    }
  }

  handleAdd = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      addedItems: update(this.state.addedItems, {
        [item.id]: {$set: item}
      })
    })
  }

  handleRemove = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      addedItems: update(this.state.addedItems, {
        $unset: [item.id]
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NumberWrap>
          {this.state.placeholder.map(num => {
            const item = this.state.addedItems[num];
            return (
              <Numbers>
                {item &&
                  <Product
                    key={num}
                    {...item}
                    remove={() => {
                      this.handleRemove(item);
                    }}
                  />
                }
              </Numbers>
            );
          })}
        </NumberWrap>
        <CardWrap>
          {this.state.data.map(item =>
            <Product
              {...item}
              add={() => {
                this.handleAdd(item)
              }}
            />
          )}
        </CardWrap>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: the placeholder numbers don't show in this example but it works apart from that

Comment: I also one problem with this, if you click on box 4 for instance it will add into the 4th position whereas I need it to go into the first position